# When changing the program size, the image box should automatically expand

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a program size and if I increase this at the corners is to increase the ImageBox automatically with.Unfortunately, this does not work yet, since an error occurs.Has anyone a solution to this, if I change the form size, which also increases the ImageBox automatically.I would like the size of the ImageBox then also larger, if I change the size of the form.

```
private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                imgPreview.Source = zoom(imgPreview, new System.Drawing.Size(Convert.ToInt32(this.Width), Convert.ToInt32(this.Height))); // Mistake is here
            }
```

---

```
        System.Drawing.Image zoom(System.Drawing.Image img, System.Drawing.Size size)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, img.Width + (img.Width * size.Width / 100), img.Height + (img.Height * size.Height / 100));
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            return bmp;
        }
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="Vorschau.UCOxyplotPreview"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Vorschau"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="379.573" Width="539.634" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
    <Image x:Name="imgPreview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="109,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350"/>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you show your xaml as well?

Comment: Thank you. Done.

Comment: Is there a reason for the following properties: HorizontalAlignment, Height, Margin, VerticalAlignment and Width?

Comment: No. This was generated automatically.

Comment: Ok, have a look at my answer.

Comment: System.Drawing namespace is not WPF but WindowsForm. If you stick with WPF, the Image control is automatically resized, don't need to register a SizeChanged. I suggest you try to change your UserControl (as Mighty Badaboom suggest), does it have to display something else than the Image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the properties `HorizontalAlignment`, `Height`, `Margin`, `VerticalAlignment` and `Width`. The `Image` should resize automatically when done.

//edit
Just to show you a minimalistic example. When using this code your `Image` size will change your `Window` size is changing. That's why I think the problem is in your `Window` xaml where you use your `UserControl` with the `Image`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
    <Image Source="IMG_20160831_105257778.jpg" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have expressed myself indistinctly. I would like the size of the ImageBox then also larger, if I change the size of the form.

Comment: So everything is working and your image is resizing?

Comment: It is always only in the middle with the same size.

Comment: Do you have your UserControl inside a Window? If yes: please show me our Window xaml as well for reproducing your problem.

Comment: @GabelUndMesser That's because the UserControl size itself never changes. Make sure you remove these properties from the UserControl on the main view too.

Comment: I have times a new project created and this also tried out there. Unfortunately, the size does not change there either. Do I still have to tell the project, if the size of the application should change the size of the picture also change?

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Right now it worked. `<Image x:Name="image"  Height="291"  Width="519" Source="Hydrangeas.jpg"/>` <- this didn't work `<Image Source="Hydrangeas.jpg"/>` <- this worked

Comment: Your welcome. One of the advantages in WPF is the resizing. You can have a look at Grid to get familiar with rezising layouts ;)